# how to include new line in scipt log which is calling sql file and that sql file is giving lot of errors

Tags: unix

I have written a shell script which is calling another sql file, which is disabling triggers in oracle. 
but this sql file is generating lot of oracle errors and in log file of script, I am getting response like

 ORA-21021 -- oracle errros ORA-20111 -- **oracle errors**
I would like to add a new line getting the oracle errors something like

```
ORA-21021 --** oracle errors**
ORA-20111 --** oracle errors**
```

How this can be done?

sql file code:

```
alter trigger trigger_name1 disable;
alter trigger trigger_name2 disable;
alter trigger trigger_name3 disable;
alter trigger trigger_name4 disable;
alter trigger trigger_name4 disable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by below method:

```
SQL=$(echo "$SQL" | sed -e 's/ERROR/\\n\rERROR/g')

echo $SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with perl

```
perl -pe 's/ORA-\d/\n$&/g' <oldfile >newfile
```

to add a newline before sequences ORA- followed by a number (\d)